# Should the encoder be trained for more steps in VAEs?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, evidence-lower-bound

This is based on my interpretation of how the ELBO loss works. The log likelihood of the data is equal to the ELBO + KL Divergence term.

$$\operatorname{log} p_{\theta}(x) = \underbrace{\mathbb {E}_{q_{\phi} (z)}\left [\operatorname{log}\frac{p_{\theta}(x|z)p(z)}{q_{\phi} (z)} \right ]}_{\text{ELBO}} + D_{KL}(q_{\phi} (z) ~||~p_{\theta}(z|x) )$$

Now the LHS is constant with respect to the parameters of the encoder $\phi$ but not with respect to the parameters of the decoder $\theta$. Most explanations I have come across say that because the LHS is constant, maximizing the ELBO would reduce the KL Divergence term and this would tighten the bound. But in practice we optimize both the encoder and decoder parameters jointly. My intuition says that it would make more sense to train the encoder for more steps before training the decoder and repeating the process. So I would really appreciate any clarification on the subject.

Comment: Expectations are hard to approximate, you cannot know how many sample you'll need... however, seems that 1 is enough, that's why you dont train it for multiple steps